# Accessing multidimensional array in the WHERE clause

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, multidimensional-array

I have a function where I pass in a multidimensional array to be used in the WHERE clause. I think I may have to use a FOR LOOP but not sure.

How do I access passed in parameter inside the query?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.select_locations(coordinates TEXT[][])
 RETURNS SETOF public.locations AS
$BODY$

DECLARE item public.locations;

BEGIN
   select * INTO item from public.locations where latitude, longitude NOT IN coordinates;

   RETURN item;
END

$BODY$
  LANGUAGE PLPGSQL VOLATILE
   COST 100;
```

Test call:

```
 select * from
 public.select_locations


(Array[array['42.449630','-123.758012'],array['42.456591','-123.844708']]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To return every row in locations that isn't in coordinates arg (if I understand what you want), you can do the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.select_locations(coordinates TEXT[][])
  RETURNS SETOF public.locations AS
$BODY$
  DECLARE item public.locations;
BEGIN
  for item in select * from public.locations where array[latitude,longitude] not in (SELECT array[coordinates[i][1], coordinates[i][2]] FROM
generate_series(array_lower(coordinates,1),array_upper(coordinates,1)) i) loop
    return next item;
  end loop;
return;
END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE PLPGSQL VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

Table locations has latitude and longitude as text type columns.
PostgreSQL version 9.1.

Comment: Great answer Allan. I was struggling with it for couple of days.

Comment: Thanks, happy to help.